# strange pop noise sounded like a blown tire

Tags: dodge

i was driving down the road and i heards and pop like the tire blew and while i had to limp it to a pull over spot it sounded exactly like a tire blew. I then pulled over to check and the tired were all aired up. When I went to take back off i never heard it the rest of the way home. what could this be? I checked the tired and once lose so im guessing wheel bearing went out.(1997 Dodge dakota)

Comment: Are you sure it wasn’t another car near you that made the noise? Maybe another car had a burst tyre.

Comment: I never thought about that but im gussing it was me bc it sounded like it was right there with me the whole time and the car I passed was going the opposite direction

Comment: Did you feel anything in the steering wheel, feet or seat at the time of the pop?

Comment: not that I remember

Comment: You would usually feel a mechanical failure somewhere if it "popped". If you unknowingly run over an object in the road you probably would have felt it in your feet. I'm inclined to think that the pop came from an outside source. But it might be a good idea to have an experienced mechanic check over the suspension for safety. Especially on a car this age.

Comment: Just a thought, have you checked your spare tyre?

Comment: When a tyre runs over a bird like a pigeon, that can make a pop noise, sadly.

Comment: I checked all suspension and tires and it doesn't have a spare tire on it but thats what I was think that I ran something over and it was slapping the fever well and I didnt catch it. that's what im hoping for atleast do yall think its safe to drive

Comment: We can't really assure you it's safe to drive until it is physically inspected by a qualified mechanic.

Comment: I'll have it lined at and meet yall know!!!

Comment: thank you guys so much i found the problem the top bolt came out of my caliper on the front passenger side and was riding against the rim or rotor im gues